# I Use for loop inside django template, but Django Generic editing views don't send data to template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm very new to django. I'm creating student attendance system. I can add classes and students in each class. But when it comes to check attendance I get stuck. My model, form, view and template for checking attendance are here:

**models.py**

```
choice_list = [(1, 'Present'), (2, "Absent")]
class AttendanceChecking(models.Model):
    pupil = models.ForeignKey(ClassPupils, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pupil_attendance')
    pupil_class = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClassess, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='class_attendance')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='responsible_attendance')
    date = models.DateField()
    mark_attendance = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choice_list, default='Present')
```

**forms.py**

```
choice_list = [(1, 'Present'), (2, "Absent")]

class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mark_attendance = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list)
    class Meta:
        model = AttendanceChecking
        fields = ('mark_attendance',)
```

**views.py**

```
class AttendanceListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = AttendanceForm
    context_object_name = 'classes'
    model = SchoolClassess
    template_name = 'app_school/attendance_list_view.html'
```

**attendance_list_view.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% for pupil in classes.pupils.all %}
            {{ pupil.pupil_lname }} {{pupil.pupil_fname}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My purpose is creating a table which is the list of all students in a class and additional column for attendance as shown in image [students list for checking attendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mTI7.png). when **confirm** button is clicked the data must be saved db table.
I tried, but when I use CreateView or FormView the data isn't showed in template with for loop.

If you can help me using generic editing views, I would be appreciated.

Comment: what context is being sent to the `classes` variable in the template?

Comment: Classes in school, like 1- a class, 1-b class and so on. Each class has about 30 pupils, and school has about 33 classes from 1 to 11, letters are used for classification in born place of same aged pupils